# Regular expression to parse my string

Tags: regex

I'm pretty new to Regular Expression and can't find a way to parse my string.  I have a weird string in a field in a database and would like to apply some regex on it to extract "records".  Here's an example of two records:

`a:4:{i:1;s:3:"233";i:2;s:3:"119";i:3;s:2:"95";i:5;s:3:"169";}
a:2:{i:15;s:3:"267";i:16;s:3:"270";}`

The pattern I want to extract is:

`i:1;s:3:"233"
i:2;s:3:"119"
i:3;s:2:"95"
i:5;s:3:"169"
i:15;s:3:"267"
i:16;s:3:"270"`

So what I thought would do the trick is:
`i:[0-9]*s:[0-9]*:\"[0-9]*\";`

But it's not working :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: That looks like PHP `serialize()` format. Why don't you use `unserialize` to decode it?

Comment: Maybe, no clue about PHP but the application that writes data to the database is programmed in PHP but I'm dealing with ETL tool to extract the data from that MySQL database.  I just need to revert this data back to records rather than having it in one field which is useless to me.

Comment: Next time you ask a regex question, please add other tags to precise the language/flavour. It's painful not to kwow what kind of extensions are available. I only answered because I was sure no back reference or any other not universally available thing was needed but that's not always the case

Comment: ok, sorry.  First time using Stackoverflow.  Didn't expect that structure to be something "usual" in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just forgot one `;` :

```
i:[0-9]*;s:[0-9]*:\"[0-9]*\";
```

Comment: I missed the semicolon. Needs to change my eyeglasses!! :D